# how can i put string after int in c++

Tags: c++, string

i want to create a c++ program like that

Design and implement using C++, a class "Student" that stores the student id, name,
40
address and marks in five different subjects (in an array having five elements). Assume
that marks are out of 100. The class should have a constructor, a member function for
input of marks and an additional member functions which prints the student details
and marks, along with total marks and percentage. Write the main function which
creates two such student objects and displays their details

i want to insert student name and marks in this program but i am getting error why ...

this is my program..

please provide solution with example

```
     #include <iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;

class student{

private:
    int id;
    char *name;
    int marks[5];
    char *address;
public:
    student();
    void input_detail();
    void display_detail();
    double total_marks();
    double percentage();

};

student::student(){
    id=0;
    name='\0';
    marks[5]=NULL;
    address='\0';

}
void student::input_detail(){
    int i=1,j=0;
    cout<<"please enter student id: "<<endl;
    cin>>id;
    cout<<"please enter student name: "<<endl;
    gets(name);
    for(i=1,j=0;i<6;i++,j++){
        cout<<"enter marks "<<i<<" subject : "<<endl;
        cin>>marks[j];
    }
    cout<<"please enter student address : "<<endl;
    gets(address);

}

double student::total_marks(){
    double total_marks;
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        total_marks=total_marks+marks[i];
    }
    return total_marks;
}

double student::percentage(){

    double percentage;

    percentage=total_marks()/500*100;
    return percentage;

}
void student::display_detail(){
    int i=1,j=0;
    cout<<"student id: "<<id<<endl;
    cout<<"student id: "<<name<<endl;
    for(i=1,j=0;i<6;i++,j++){
        cout<<"marks "<<i<<" subject : "<<marks[j]<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"student address : "<<address<<endl;
    cout<<"student total marks : "<<total_marks()<<endl;
    cout<<"student percentage : "<<percentage()<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    student s1;
    s1.input_detail();
    s1.display_detail();
    return 0;
}
```

i am getting this output

```
please enter student id:
anil
please enter student name:
please enter student address :
annn
student id: 0
student id: anil
student address : annn
student total marks : 1.1331e-317
student percentage : 0
```

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 19.901 s
Press any key to continue.

but where is the student marks it is not showing in program

Comment: And *what* error do you get? *Where* do you get it?

Comment: Oh, and doing e.g. `name[100]=NULL;` will lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as you write a zero out of bounds of the array. If you want to make sure the "string" is "empty" just set the first character to the string terminator `'\0'`.

Comment: please enter student id:
anil
please enter student name:
please enter student address :
annn
student id: 0
student id: anil
student address : annn
student total marks : 1.1331e-317
student percentage : 0

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 19.901 s
Press any key to continue.

Comment: Since this is C++ you'd be better off using `std:string` than `char` arrays.

Comment: Also, check the condition in that loop in the `input_details` function, when will `i` *ever* be larger than `6`?

Answer (score 0):

A quick check shows me two errors:

1. The `for` condition is the opposite of what you think: when it's `true` the loop continues, when it's false the loop quits. A loop like `for(int i=0; i>6; i++){...}` will never run because the condition is false when starting (0 is not bigger than 6).
2. When you declare double a variable in C++ you need to initialize it; this error is present when computing the sum (start with `double total_marks=0`).

There are indeed many other errors and questionable approaches, but those are probably better discussed in class...